# have opened HTTPS port but still no response

Tags: firewalls, nmap, ports

I have `watchguard firewall` and server behind it configured with NAT.

I was told to open port https for 1 of the server.

I have create a rule from any to the NAT server to allow port 443, the windows firewall has already disabled too. but when I scan with `nmap`, `nmap` shows that the port is blocked :

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
443/tcp closed https
```

and I scan with TCPing, it shows "no response" answer :

```
Probing 27.50.16.148:443/tcp - No response - time=2001.491ms
```

Does it happen because there is no web server?
The current condition is that the application that will be built on port 443 has not been created yet.

Comment: hello and welcome to security.se. unfortunately, your question is not about security at all but about how to configure your network. I would have suggested the question be moved to serverfault but you're not even providing enough information for solving the problem there. I'm therefore recommending your question to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

A TCP port is considered open if a client can connect to it. This means that there 1) need to be a service on this port and destination host and 2) that it the service is reachable from the client. Configuring a packet filter like Watchguard to let packets pass just lets the client reach the service if there would be any but does not create the service itself.